# Where can i store data(text and image) in android

Tags: android, xml, database, storage

i'm writing an application that needs to store some data,and picture. For example place's information. this information don't need to change very often. and
 I have seen that databases are
stored under /data/data/package_name/databases
I decided to store my data under /data/data/package_name/files.
With the emulator i can see all these files (databases)
under the proposed directories but moving the application on a real
device and installing a file system browser i cannot see any file
under /data. i know that there are some security constrain in (not-rooted) device. However, are there any suggestion about the solution.. where can i store these data and how? because i'm quite new to android. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't see it on the device is basically just as you said; the device isn't rooted, so other apps don't have access to the /data folder.

This is okay though, because you can still store your files there. Your app has access to anything under /data/data/package_name/, you just won't be able to see it in a file browser unless you root. This is normally a good thing, to keep average users from mucking around with your databases/files.

Read up more on storage methods [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, however, i create only a table from code but inside still empty. I insert data by pull a file out and insert by SQLite Browser then, put it back to the data/data/package_name/file.db 
This solution, after run the program i can see the list of information in Emulator. But moving the application on a real device, i cannot see any file. How should i do?